# Why am I getting no method matching Complex(::Sym)?

Tags: julia, sympy, pycall

I am having one function to be executed, it has been compiled but for the execution it shows me a MethodError, here is the function

For this function I'm using SymPy

```
function op_mat(op)
           op = op.as_poly(domain="C")
           op_a = op.x.gens
           nab = op.length()
           op_ab = ones(SymPy.Sym, nab)
           coef = zeros(Complex, nab)
           mat = zeros(Int64, length(op_a), nab)
           for (i, (ps, c)) in enumerate(op.as_dict())
               for (j, p) in enumerate(ps)
                   mat[j, i] = p
                   op_ab[i] = op_a[j]^p * op_ab[i]
               end
               coef[i] = c
           end

           return op_a, op_ab, mat, coef
       end
```

The error message that I'm having is this one:

```
  Complex(::T<:Number) where T<:Number at boot.jl:718
  Complex(::Real) at complex.jl:16
  Complex(::T<:Real, ::T<:Real) where T<:Real at complex.jl:12
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] convert(::Type{Complex}, ::Sym) at ./number.jl:7
 [2] setindex!(::Array{Complex,1}, ::Sym, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:766
 [3] op_mat(::Sym) at ./REPL[3]:13
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[7]:1
```

Comment: What's the type of `c` in `coef[i] = c`?  Before that line add `@show typeof(c)`

Comment: Can you add the example polynomial with which you called the function?

Comment: Try assigning with N(c)?

Comment: for the polynomial you can try a simple one like `op=x+y` where `x=symbols("x")` and `y=symbols("y")`

Comment: the type of `c`is `Sym`@giordano

Answer (score 1):

since the type of c is `Sym` i should have only change the type to complex `coef[i]=complex(c)` or `coef[i]=N(c)`

Comment: You can also specify `coef` more explicitly, as in `coef = zeros(Complex{Float64}, nab)`, and this will  allow the conversion to go through.